# How to share a jupyter notebook with colleagues (virtual private cloud required)?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I need to share Jupyter notebooks with my colleagues. My company is pretty strict about data, sharing, etc so it needs to be on our private cloud. We use AWS. SageMaker is ok, but we also want to share the same environment I set up for my notebook. We don't have huge budgets for Domino Data Labs. Any methods / tools, even if low cost, you recommend? Really appreciaet the help.

Background on what i tried: 
I don't even know where to start..
Our dev ops guys dont have bandwidth to do this for a while, but it's crushing us because we have a deliverable due soon

Comment: Why can't you just start an EC2 instance, restrict access with security groups and run your Jupyter there?

Comment: As long as your colleagues have access to the AWS account you are using for Sagemaker notebooks, they should be able to access the same notebook instance you are using.